# What are ways to improve the accuracy of the spring constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, spring

[image]When taking a static approach to finding the spring constant  $k$, the only improvement I can think of is modifying the length of the string attached to the spring and weight. Can anyone provide some hints or guide me in the right direction on how I can further improve a static spring setup?

I'm suppose to come up with a method to improve this setup in order to get a more accurate spring constant.

Comment: Depending on how far you might go, you could use the eigenfrequency of the system

Comment: Or just write down the equations of movement, solve it and measure it. E.g. the amount of time it takes to run 100 cycles

Comment: ah there's no time involved when using f = kx

Answer (score 1):

The spring constant is best thought of not as a single number to be measured, but as a relationship between two quantities: force and distance.  As one quantity changes, so does the other. So, just as averaging multiple measurements can yield a more accurate result, measuring multiple points in a relationship can yield a more accurate $k$. The analog of averaging in a relatioship is curve fitting. When you have a list of varying weights and displacements, you can find the line that passes closest to your data in a plot (the technical term is linear regression). From the slope of this line you can find $k$.

Comment: I already know that you can find k with the slope derived from the relationship of the displacement and mass. What I'm asking is how to change the setup in order to increase the accuracy, please help.

Comment: @jakelawliet You need to provide more details about your current measurement. What are you measuring (from where to where) and how are you measuring? I can't make any suggestions if I don't know what you're currently doing.